# delete symlink that points to itself

Tags: 20.04, filesystem, symbolic-link

I accidentally created a symbolic link that points to itself in the same directory. I tried `ln -sfn` and `rm -f`.
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.
It's in my `Pictures` folder:

`picture_link -> picture_link`

Is there an easy bash command to delete it or do I need to compile a C program to access some low level API?

Answer (score 2):

Symbolic links are not special, you can remove them like any file.

But `rm .`  tries to remove the current directory which isn't going to work, and `-f` suppresses any error message you might get.

So try `rm picture_link` with no extra options and see what happens.

Comment: The period in that context was denoting the end of my English sentence. I tried rm and rm -f on that file.

Comment: Use rm without -f and add the error to your question.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I owe everyone here an apology. I remember a while ago I experimented with setting the immutable bit on a few directories as a security experiment to avoid symlink attacks. (That kind of attack is part of a malware strategy I've seen on some websites.) I unset that bit on the directory containing the broken self-referencing link and I was able to delete the link afterwards. Again, sorry and thanks everyone.

Comment: @RogerTrussell . Please post this comment as an a answer and accept it.

Comment: along with the error that led you to figure this out...

Answer (score 1):

Upon popular demand, I'll explain what I did to solve this problem:
So here is an oversimplified setup in Bash

(There were a number of steps I think in getting the symlink to point to itself. The important thing is I have a self-referencing link that I want to delete.)

```
rogman@rogman-ThinkCentre-M75e:~$ mkdir bad_links
rogman@rogman-ThinkCentre-M75e:~$ cd bad_links
rogman@rogman-ThinkCentre-M75e:~/bad_links$ ln -s loopy loopy
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rogman rogman 5 Mar 13 09:52 loopy -> loopy
```

Now I set the immutability bit on the bad_links directory.
I need root or "sudo" permissions.

```
rogman@rogman-ThinkCentre-M75e:~$ sudo chattr +i bad_links
```

Now I list the immutability bit:

```
rogman@rogman-ThinkCentre-M75e:~$ lsattr | grep "bad_links"
----i---------e----- ./bad_links
```

Now I try to delete the symlink:

```
rogman@rogman-ThinkCentre-M75e:~/bad_links$ rm loopy
rm: cannot remove 'loopy': Operation not permitted

rogman@rogman-ThinkCentre-M75e:~/bad_links$ sudo rm loopy
rm: cannot remove 'loopy': Operation not permitted

rogman@rogman-ThinkCentre-M75e:~/bad_links$ sudo rm -f loopy
rm: cannot remove 'loopy': Operation not permitted
```

Well maybe if I can't delete it, I'll try to change where it points:

```
rogman@rogman-ThinkCentre-M75e:~/bad_links$ ln -sfn ../blah123.txt loopy
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'loopy': Operation not permitted
```

That didn't work.
I'll remove the immutability bit on the directory

```
rogman@rogman-ThinkCentre-M75e:~$ chattr -i bad_links
chattr: Operation not permitted while setting flags on bad_links
rogman@rogman-ThinkCentre-M75e:~$ sudo chattr -i bad_links
rogman@rogman-ThinkCentre-M75e:~$
```

Now let's remove the symlink normally

```
rogman@rogman-ThinkCentre-M75e:~/bad_links$ rm loopy
rogman@rogman-ThinkCentre-M75e:~/bad_links$
```